# Resize ext4 backwards?

Tags: linux, partitioning

So, I initially installed windows and linux mint on my ssd in dual boot configuration. I gave windows a full 60 gb despite how little I use it, because, well, it's windows. Problem is, I DO use my linux partition, and am really starting to get crunched on space. I'd like to resize my partition; which I'm only margionally familiar with.

To further complicate matters, I installed windows first, so I would first have to shrink the windows partition (no big issue) and then resize the ext4 partition to consume the space. To my knowlege, partitions can not be resized in that direction; but I'm hoping someone can help me out.

Any ideas or takers?
Thank you.

Comment: These days it is possible to write to NTFS partitions (using ntfs-3g), you might be able to solve some of your problems simply by sharing storage.

Comment: I suppose it couldn't hurt to port my music files over. That's a good 5 gb right there.

Answer (score 2):

Resizing your partitions is easily possible and usually a pretty safe process, however, please create a backup before trying any of this - just in case.

There are several tools to resize partitions (and their various filesystems), one of the easiest and free choices is [GParted](http://gparted.org). Make sure to download a Live CD or USB image and boot from there (resizing partitions while they are mounted is a more involved process). From then on, you get a rather self-explanatory graphical user interface that lets you resize your partitions. There's also a [manual](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual) available, if you need explanations for each step required.

Comment: He wants to move the beginning of the partition.

Comment: This is exactly the same process in GParted. It will first shrink NTFS, then move the ext4 filesystem to the new starting sector of the partition. (It might take a while longer than just growing a filesystem in the other direction, though)

Comment: True, it seems the same from the user’s POV, but it’s not. It will move the entire contents of the partition. If anything goes wrong during this transfer, you might well lose all data.

Comment: Hence the friendly reminder to take a backup. :)